# Problem with clipboard class

Tags: vb.net

I have created a application which checks if the text in clipboard starts with "file", and if it starts with the word file it process the clipboard text and then replaces it with < a href="some value">

For example it the clipboard string is

> file:///C:/Users/Searock/Desktop/dotnet/Apress.Pro.VB.2008.and.the.dot.NET.3.5.Platform.3rd.Edition.Mar.2008.html#link22

then the program will process the clipboard txt and then replace it with < a href="#link22">

Here's my code :

Variable Declaration :

```
Dim strProcess As String
Dim intPos As Integer
Dim check As String
Dim strBuilder As New StringBuilder()
```

Form Load :

```
bwCopyPaste.RunWorkerAsync()
```

BackGroundWorker DoWork event :

```
While (True)
     Thread.Sleep(150)

     If bwCopyPaste.CancellationPending = True Then
          Exit While
     End If

     check = Clipboard.GetText()

     If check <> "" Then

     If check.StartsWith("file") Then

     Try

          strProcess = Clipboard.GetText()

          intPos = strProcess.LastIndexOf("#")

          strProcess = strProcess.Substring(intPos, strProcess.Length - intPos)

          strBuilder.AppendFormat("<a href=""{0}"">", strProcess)

          Clipboard.SetText(strBuilder.ToString())

     Catch ex As Exception

          MessageBox.Show("Invalid Url", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
          Application.Restart()

     Finally
          strBuilder.Clear()
     End Try

     End If

End If
End While
```

I don't get any runtime errors, but even if there is any text in the clipboard, this statement

```
check = Clipboard.GetText()
If check <> "" Then
```

always returns me a false value.

Can anyone point me to a right direction ?

Thanks.

Comment: Open Notepad and type some text, then copy it to the clipboard and see if it works. Make sure its Notepad and not like Microsoft Word or something.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried checking the clipboard by pasting something in notepad, there is a text still i get the condition as false, I think Clipboard class can only be used by STA as Stephen Wrighton has said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that BackgroundWorkers are MTA (Multi Thread Apartments) and the Clipboard class can only be used by STA (Single Thread Apartments) threads.

Try something like this in  your load where "bwCopyPaste.RunWorkerAsync()" resides.

```
If Clipboard.ContainsText() then
   bwCopyPaste.RunWorkerAsync(ClipBoard.GetText())
End if
```

Then you can get at the value passed into the background worker through it's eventArgument.