# Back button in a vb.net program

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write the code for a back button in my VB.NET app. But it is not working. What is wrong with it?

```
Private Sub BackBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BackBtn.Click
    Dim returntext As String = Clipboard.GetText()
    lblDictword.Text = returntext
    Dim returnHtmlText As String = Nothing

    If (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText)) Then
        returnHtmlText = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText)
        'Clipboard.SetText(replacementHtmlText, TextDataFormat.Html)
        Clipboard.SetText(returnHtmlText, TextDataFormat.UnicodeText)
    End If
    lblDictword.Text = returnHtmlText
    'Return returnHtmlText

    Dim count As Integer = myStrings.Length
    If count > 1 Then
        Dim s As String = myStrings.ElementAt(count - xd)
        xd = Array.IndexOf(myStrings, s)
        lblDictword.Text = s
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the problem? Does it explode?

Comment: WHAT are you trying to do? what does a back button do? Backspace? Backwards in a history file?

Comment: back button for a text box. if it clicked it should display the previously loaded text.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an VB.NET expert, but usually getting access to clipboard isn't as easy as it looks. 
Check this:

[Problem with clipboard class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303350/problem-with-clipboard-class)

It can be only a tip, not really solution. Look into your clipboard functionallity